# Как как вставить формулу в диапазон?

Tags: excel, vba

Пытаюсь написать код для вставки формулы в диапазон, не уверен что вообще правильно делаю. Постоянно ругается на $ и _. Подскажите как лучше сделать

```
Public Sub calc()

Range("I7:Al228).Select
Selection.Formula = "VLOOKUP($E76&"_"&IF($H76="день",1,2),'склад 3-3 с ночными'!$B$12:$AG$19,1+V$6,FALSE)"
Selection.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Range отсутствуют закрывающие кавычки. В тексте (а формула в коде записана текстом) кавычки нужно задваивать. Выделять (Select) диапазон для вставки формулы не нужно. Нужна именно формула в ячейке или необходимо получить значение?

Comment: @vikttur Нужно чтобы формула вставилась в каждую ячейку диапазона I7:AL228,    и в итоге получалось значение в каждой ячейке. Не знаю, так ли объяснил

Comment: Задача в чем? Можно вставить формулу и она останется на листе. А можно без вставки формулы получать значение макросом

Comment: @vikttur У меня скрипт который исходя из значений на листе "Настройка" создает лист "График" с сотрудниками, мне в этот скрипт нужно встроить код, чтобы так же при создании листа данный график заполнялся сменами, решил сделать именно таким способом.. просто вставив формулу, перенаправив на другой лист.

Comment: Кроме описанных выше ошибок - пытаетесь вставить одинаковую формулу во все ячейки диапазона. Покажите ссылку на пример.

Comment: @vikttur Добавил скрин, как по сути должно быть. Сейчас вся эта таблица создается без заполнения значений, я хотел встроить формулу в код. Изначально я хотел сделать по другому, сделать поиск значения в определенном столбце, случае это "Е", если бы он нашел определенное значение, к примеру "2", он бы копировал диапазон ячеек с другого листа. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать как было бы проще сделать все это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В небольшом коде много ошибок, о них написано в комментариях.

Правильно: или вставлять формулы со стилем ссылок `R1C1`(ссылки определяют положение ячейки, на которую ведет ссылка), или сначала вставить формулы в первую строку диапазона, потом размножить по строкам:

```
Public Sub calc_()
    With Range("I7:Al7")
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP($E76&""_""&IF($H76=""день"",1,2),'склад 3-3 с ночными'!$B$12:$AG$19,1+V$6,0)"
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
    Range("I7:Al228").FillDown
End Sub
```